# Нахождение всех циклов в ориентированном графе обходом вглубину через матрицу смежности

Tags: c++, графы, dfs

Похожий вопрос был на хабре, даже с алгоритмом, но все-таки нужна помощь с обходом графа и поиском циклов. Имеется такой граф:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Алгоритм находит только простые циклы, а как найти другие?. (Например,такой 982341289)
Подскажите, как модифицировать код.
Код:

```
void dfs(int v, int start){
    if(used[v]){
        if(v == start) {
            for (int i = 0; i < path.size(); ++i)
                cout << path[i] << " ";
            cout << v << endl;
        }
        return;
    }

    used[v] = 1;

    path.push_back(v);
    for(int i = 0; i < graph[v].size(); ++i)
        if(graph[v][i] == 1)
            dfs(i, start);

    used[v] = 0;

   path.pop_back();
}
int main() {
    graph.push_back({ 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }); //0
    graph.push_back({ 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }); //1
    graph.push_back({ 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0 }); //2
    graph.push_back({ 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }); //3
    graph.push_back({ 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }); //4
    graph.push_back({ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }); //5
    graph.push_back({ 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0 }); //6
    graph.push_back({ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 }); //7
    graph.push_back({ 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 }); //8
    graph.push_back({ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 }); //9


    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        used.resize(10, 0);
        dfs(i, i);
        //path.clear();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А других циклов — если разрешено ходить по одним и тем же вершинам многократно — вроде как бесконечно много, нет? 98, 9898, 989898 и так далее? Или какие-то ограничения вы накладываете? И еще, ваш код дает одни и те же циклы, только со сдвигом — это так и задумано? Типа 12341, 23412 и т.д.

Comment: @Harry, про одинаковые циклы со сдвигом по идеи верно, потому что они начинаются как бы в разных вершинах (12341 начался в 1 вершине и туда же пришел, а 23412 начался во 2 вершине). А насчет многократного хождения и зацикливания, даже не знаю, поэтому и спрашиваю, можно ли как-то найти сложные циклы. Из идей только ввести какую-нибудь переменную, которая будет проверять, сколько раз мы были в вершине и если, например, больше 3 то остановить.